# I can’t add AR to a project at react native expo

Tags: android, react-native, 3d, expo, augmented-reality

I can’t add AR to a project at the React native expo. Expo version 49. I tried ViroReact, ARkit, and three.js - all give errors with some missing functions or version errors. Please advise some libraries suitable for new versions of the expo, or maybe some solution; I will be very grateful. There is an option to refuse the expo, and here you can please suggest some new libraries or solutions.

I tried different options. Or ready-made libraries or some three.js solution. All of them produced errors related to versions in package.json.